# LibreOffice version by default in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is very old

Tags: 20.04

I have moved from Xubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. LibreOffice version by default in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is 6.4.7.2. Why is it very old ?

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/151304/1222991) will list out the reasons. If you need the latest version, you can certainly install it via Snap or [a `.deb` package](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/?type=deb-x86_64)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is the 2020-April release; ie. a release of Ubuntu from two years ago & is now four releases ago (*will be five in a few hours*).  You have the option of other package formats (install from source, *snap* packages etc)